# Each Time I open a terminal, I have to rewrite : source ~/.bashrc

Tags: bash, terminal

I use Mac OS Sierra.

Each time I open a new terminal, I can't use anymore my alias, I need to rewrite : `source ~/.bashrc`

I tried to quit terminal and open it again, but it happens the same thing.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Terminal opens a login shell by default, in which it loads `~/.bash_profile` and **not**  `~/.bashrc`. To source the latter on every invocation of the shell, just add the line below at your `.bash_profile` the end.

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi
```

From man page of bash:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or
>   one started with the --login option.

...

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-inter-
>   active  shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes com-
>   mands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.   After  reading
>   that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`,
>   in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one  that
>   exists  and  is  readable.  The `--noprofile` option may be used when the
>   shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Terminal, `~/.bashrc` is not read automatically. Use `~/.profile`.